# Exterior and symmetric powers of $\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{C})$ representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am taking a course on representation theory, and going through Lecture 15 of Fulton and Harris's *Representation Theory*. One of the topics we're currently covering is the example of $\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{C})$.

Let $V$ be the standard representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{C})$. If I know the weights of $V$, how do I find the weights of the representations
$$\operatorname{Sym}^n(\wedge^2V)\text{ and }\wedge^2(\wedge^2V)?$$
Since the weights of $\wedge^2V$ are the double sums of distinct weights of $V$ (let's call them $L_1+L_2,...,L_3+L_4$), I think that the weights of $\wedge^2V$ would be the double sums of these sums. But then it isn't obvious to me which are the irreducible representations over which $\wedge^2(\wedge^2V)$ decomposes.

Similarly, by writing down the weights of the representations $\operatorname{Sym}^n(\wedge^2V)$ we can deduce that $\operatorname{Sym}^n(\wedge^2V)$ are not irreducible. We can, however, create a map 
$$\varphi_n:\operatorname{Sym}^n(\wedge^2V)\to \operatorname{Sym}^{n-2}(\wedge^2V)$$
whose kernel is the irreducible representation with highest weight $n(L_1+L_2)$. But as I am having trouble just writing down the weights, I do not know how to go about proving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by the weights not being irreducible?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the representation $\operatorname{Sym}^n(\wedge^2V)$ is not irreducible by looking at the weights.

Comment: You are right that "the weights of $\wedge^2V$ would be the double sums of these sums". And the weights of $\mathrm{Sym}^n\left(\wedge^2 V\right)$ are the $n$-fold sums of not necessarily distinct double sums of distinct weights of $V$. How to get the irreps from the weights? Well, you can start by picking a highest weight, then subtract all the weights of the irrep it generates, and then iterate... That should work at least for concrete small $n$.